# Removing three20 from my project got me "Symbol(s) not found"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I was trying to remove the Three20 framework from my project. I was pretty sure I deleted them thoroughly and right now in my project there was nothing depending on a "TT" class.

However, one strange warning:

> The 'myTableView' outlet of 'File's
>   Owner' is connected to 'Table View'
>   but 'UITableView' is not a kind of
>   'TTTableView' as specified by the
>   outlet type.

But I double checked my .h file, .m file and .xib file, no "TTTableView" was used or mentioned.

Another several strange errors:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LoadAppViewController",
>   referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-DBManager in
>   MyAppDelegate.o
>
> Symbol(s) not found

I cleaned my build folder, I checked any necessary official framework is included in my project. but it didn't help for the warning or the errors.

Any one can help? Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Are you sure the tableViews class is not set to that in IB?

Comment: It has to be defined somewhere.  Just `grep -R TTTableView .` for it.

Answer (score 0):

removing Three20 framework is really difficult. Did you make sure that you have removed all the entries from your pbxproj file? When you add three20, it adds hunderds of lines in pbxproj and there is no simple way of removing them all. As per my knowledge you can only remove them mannually by opening pbxproj in text editor. The errors you are getting could be due that..